# In git, how do I remove a commit from a branch but keep that commit in a separate branch?

Tags: git

I have a **DEV** branch with a history looking like this (with each list item being a separate commit):

- feature 5
- feature 4
- feature 3
- feature 2
- feature 1

Suppose I want to "delete" **feature 3** from this branch, but I don't want to lose the code in this feature so I want to put it in it's own separate branch.

Basically, from the dev branch above, I want to end up with *two* branches looking like this:

**DEV BRANCH**:

- feature 5
- feature 4
- feature 2
- feature 1

**NEW BRANCH**:

- feature 3
- feature 2
- feature 1

Any ideas how I can achieve this in git?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move some commits to another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460514/move-some-commits-to-another-branch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new branch from `feature3`. Then `reset` `feature3` from the `dev` branch. However, if you have pushed these commits you will need to use `revert`

First create `newbranch` from `feature3`

```
git checkout dev
git branch newbranch feature3
git reset --hard feature3
```

Now if you haven't pushed to remote

```
git reset --hard feature3
```

Or if you have pushed

```
git revert feature3
```

Also, if you want to add specific commits to `newbranch`, like `feature7` you can use

```
git checkout newbranch
git cherry-pick feature7
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked flawlessly. Actually also needed the cherry-picking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#create NEW
git branch NEW commit3

#rewrite DEV
git rebase -i commit2 DEV

#in the editor remove the line "pick commit3", save and exit.
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a new branch till `feature3`:

```
git checkout <feature3_commit_id>
git checkout -b new_branch
```

To remove `feature3` from dev branch

```
git checkout dev_branch
git rebase --onto <feature2_commit_id> <feature3_commit_id> <feature5_commit_id>
```

Just FYI, you can use `git log --oneline` to find commit ids.